# Minimax problem for convex function

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have sufficiently smooth function $K(x, f)$, convex in $x$ and concave in $f$. 
I need to find $x$ such 
$$
x = \mbox{arg} \min_{x} \max_{f} K(x,f).
$$

Does convexity of any help to me here? Can I just descend to the optimal solution? Or use some version alternating between $x$ and $f$?

Do I have minimax equality theorems like 
$$
\min_{x} \max_{f} K(x,f) = \min_{f} \max_{x} K(x,f).
$$
?

Comment: If $K$ is convex, then $\max_f K(x,f)$ cannot exist for any $x$ except where $K(x,f)$ does not depend on $f$ at all.

Comment: @HenningMakholm good catch. The function is convex in one variable and concave in another.

Comment: is the (effective) domain for $x$ or $f$ bounded?

Comment: @LinAlg yes, it is bounded

Comment: Sion's minimax theorem establishes your minimax equality. Finding the saddle point is not so easy. Do you have more information on the structure of $K$?

Comment: @LinAlg yes, it comes from finite element approximation of certain PDE, it can be explored, if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [LinAlg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/373321/linalg)'s answer, by Sion minimax theorem, if one of x or f belongs to a bounded set, the strong duality holds. That is, you can interchange min and max. Generally solving saddle point problems are hard. I would suggest to use the Frank-Wolfe algorithm described [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.07797.pdf). If the feasible sets for x and f are polytope, you can easily solve the above minimax problem!